# String to double bpel

Tags: bpel

It's possible to convert a string to a double variable

```
<bpel:to part="parameters" variable="ConvPLRequest">
      <bpel:query queryLanguage="urn:oasis:names:tc:wsbpel:2.0:sublang:xpath1.0">
            <![CDATA[ns0:Temperature]]>
      </bpel:query>
</bpel:to>
```

ns0:Temerature it's a string but I need a double.

Comment: What language is it?

Comment: I 'm using eclipse bpel ,it generates the code

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried number() bpel conversion function?

Converts input a number. A string that consists of optional whitespace followed by an optional minus sign followed by a Number followed by whitespace is converted to the IEEE 754 number that is nearest (according to the IEEE 754 round-to-nearest rule) to the mathematical value represented by the string; any other string is converted to NaN. boolean true is converted to 1; boolean false is converted to 0. A node-set is first converted to a string as if by a call to the String function and then converted in the same way as a string parameter. Usage: number(input as string or boolean or node-set) Example: number('12.3') returns 12.3